# How to inject MockMvc with multiple objects in Spring Boot REST Junit test case

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a SpringBoot REST API connecting to Oracle DB.

My controller calls BusinessImpl layer and in-turn BusinessImpl calls multiple DAO layers (`Controller -> BusinessImpl -> DAO1,  DAO2, DAO3`)

The below test case works perfectly

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@TestPropertySource("classpath:dev-manifest.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "env")
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest
{
  private static final String REQUEST_URI = "/v1/registration/accounts/links";
  private MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
      MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Before
  public void setup()
  {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSave()
  {
      String testInput = "some json input";
      mockMvc.perform(post(REQUEST_URI).content(testInput).contentType(contentType))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

But I do not want to hit real database during junit test case. So I wrote a mock.

**Working Code**

```
  @Mock
  private SecurityAuditDAO securityAuditDAO;

  @InjectMocks
  private RegistrationBusinessImpl registrationBusinessImpl;

  @Test
  public void testSave()
  {
      when(securityAuditDAO.getState(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("somestring");
      SomeRequest someRequest = new SomeRequest();
      someRequest.setStatus("SUCCESS");
      SomeResponse status = registrationBusinessImpl.createUser(SomeRequest, "127.0.0.1");
  }
```

The above code worked perfectly. In businessImpl class securityAuditDAO.getState returned "somestring". But when I introduced mockMvc.perform it stopped working.

**Not Working**

```
  @Test
  public void testSave()
  {
      when(securityAuditDAO.getState(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("somestring");
      String testInput = "some json input";
      mockMvc.perform(post(REQUEST_URI).content(testInput).contentType(contentType))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

The above code was still hitting the database. So I realized that I should inject mockMvc with securityAuditDAO so I added the following line

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(securityAuditDAO).build();
```

**Code**

```
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Mock
  private SecurityAuditDAO securityAuditDAO;

  @InjectMocks
  private RegistrationBusinessImpl registrationBusinessImpl;

  @InjectMocks
  RegistrationApiController registrationApiController;  

  @Before
  public void setup()
  {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(securityAuditDAO).build();
    //this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(registrationApiController).build();
    //ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mockMvc, "securityAuditDAO", securityAuditDAO);
  }
```

I tried injecting  securityAuditDAO. But if I do that, my other autowired instances in BusinessImpl were null.
How to inject securityAuditDAO without affecting others or how to inject both webApplicationContext and securityAuditDAO.
Also tried ReflectionTestUtils.setField but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: instead of trying to mock your DAO, why cant you just use an in memory DB for testing. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Comment: I already tried that. None of the in-memory database is fully compatible with Oracle.